# Closing a form from the Load handler

Tags: c#, winforms, objectdisposedexception

I have a very strange behavior that only seems to happen on one form.

Basically I am creating an instance of a `Form`, and calling `Show()` to display the form non-blocking. In that form's `Load` event handler, I have some logic that may call `this.Close()` under certain circumstances. This closes the form, but then the form `Show()` method in the client code throws an `ObjectDisposedException`.

The stack trace from the ObjectDisposedException is as follows:

> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.FocusActiveControlInternal()
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
>    ...etc.

This is what I'm seeing happen:

1. `Control.Show()` is called
2. my form is launched
3. the `OnFormLoad` method is called
4. the `FormLoad` event handler is called, inside of which I call `this.Close()`
5. the `OnFormClosing` method is called
6. the `FormClosing` event handler is called
7. `Dispose` is called on my form and all it's user controls

and then somewhere toward the end of the `Control.Show()` method, it tries to get a handle to the form, which freaks out and throws an exception because the object is marked disposed.

My real question is, why can I do this exact same thing on every other form I have without exceptions? Is it a GC issue? I've tried putting a `GC.Collect()` call right after the `this.Close()` and it makes no difference. Like I said, it happens 100% of the time on this form, and never anywhere else, regardless of child user controls, scope of the form variable, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old issue but no one seemed to have posted the obvoius answer.

You say you call `Control.Show()` and then `Form.Close()` and then the form is Disposed of. Well, unless you use MDI or use `ShowDialog` that's just as documented. Though, the short version of the `Close()` documentation is "Closes the form", it actually also disposes it implicitly under certain conditions.

See the remarks section:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx

If you want to show a form again. Use the `Hide()` method instead of `Close()`.

Hope that helps other searching souls.

And guys, don't stop searching at "I don't know why it works sometimes". That becomes buggy software with lots of defensive "I'll call this method again just in case" stuff. Not good.

Comment: I don't do windows dev anymore unfortunately, but this sounds right. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

The best way to do so :

```
 this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
```

this is the most simple way you wont get ObjectDisposedException

Comment: This works but the form maybe flicker, because BeguinInvoke puts the command to close at the end of the event queue of the form.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, hate to answer my own question, but this was driving me nuts, and it was one of the hardest bugs to reproduce I've ever seen.

On my form I'm overriding the OnFormLoad and OnFormClose methods, where I save/restore the form's Size, Location, and WindowState to/from the registry. I took this code out and it fixed the problem. The weird thing is, I put it back and the problem didn't come back.

I finally reproduced the problem: you have to let the form open fully, maximize it, and then close it so that the Maximized state is saved to the registry. Then when you open it again, it will set it to Maximized, and if it closes in the Load handler, it tries to access the Size/Location as it's closing. Apparently accessing these values in the OnFormClosing method causes the form to try to focus IF AND ONLY IF the form is maximized, which is illegal, since the form has been disposed.

So basically, you can't access Form display properties in the OnFormClosing method of a form, if that form is going to call Close from it's Load event.(Unless you check the Disposed prop first)

pretty specific piece of Winforms wisdom I know, but I'm writing it down anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to close a form as if the user pressed the cross in the upper right corner (usually means cancel), just add the following code.

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
this.Close();
```

This also works in the form load function:

```
private void MyForm_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some initializations

    if (!ContinueLoadingForm())
    {
         this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
         this.Close();
         return;
    }
    // continue loading the form
}
```

If you don't want the form to be visible for a short while, set the Visible property false (for example in the designer or constructor), and set it back to true when you are certain the program can continue loading.

Comment: Can't seem to avoid the form being displayed for a moment though.

Answer (score 3):

In load event is not realy good idea close the form. Do it after the Activated event.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected override void CreateHandle()
   {
        base.CreateHandle();

        if (FormMustClose)  //FormMustClose is a variable in the loadevent.
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, without looking closely at it, that the cleanest way to accomplish what you want might be to make a custom form class deriving from `Form`, and override `OnFormLoad(...)` and/or `Show()` to check for your condition and cancel out early.

That said, I don't know why it would work sometimes and not other times.

Comment: actually, that is the case here. I didn't mention it b/c all of my forms are that way. The base form overrides OnFormLoad and OnFormClose, but it just does registry stuff in those methods. The call sequence is the same in all forms.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

They may have a timer on this form, that is being initialized and enabled in their FormLoad event.  The timer would need to be disabled and stopped as well, before the form was closed, if the timer is trying to access the form when it's fired.

I've seen forms before that do this...

Comment: good thought, but no timers on this form. several user controls though, but I checked to make sure all of their Dispose methods are being called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping into the .net code to see what line of code is being called when the exception is occuring? If you have VS 2008 you can do so by going to Tools --> Options --> Debugging and select the Enable .NET Framework Source Stepping. Be warned, this may take a while to download all of the necessary files, but this way you can step into the form.Show() and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: no, I wish. I'm using VS 2005. I checked reflector though, and it's just like the call stack says: right near the end of the Control.Show it calls FocusActiveControlInternal, which calls the Handle getter, which throws the exception if it's disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out it's a little simpler and more generic than I thought, but still weird and obscure.

If you're saving/loading the form Size/Location/WindowState when the form loads/closes like we do, you have to make sure that the OnLoad method calls base.OnLoad first so that the Form Load event handler fires, and THEN set the properties. Not doing so will only cause a problem if the form calls Close from inside the Load method. You'll get an ObjectDisposedException on the Show call after the form closing event is done.

My head hurts.

Answer (score 0):

Form.Shown() Is the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, setting the DialogResult of the form will close the form - may have to be other than DialogResult.None.  (i.e. you don't need to then call the Form.Close() method).

The issue is also in part that if elsewhere in code, you are accessing a property of the form or control within it, that may prevent the form from closing.

It may also be best if as has been suggested, you have a property e.g.

```
private bool _loadedOk = false;
```

in your form which you set in your initialisation code.  In one of the later events after Form_Loaded, you then interrogate this and close the form if it's false.

Perhaps someone can suggest the best event to do this in??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the form without flicker, the best way I found was override SetVisibleCore Method:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{

...
    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
    {
        if (value && !IsHandleCreated && !ContinueLoadingForm())
        {
            base.SetVisibleCore(false);
            this.Close();
            return;
        }

        base.SetVisibleCore(value);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
...
var myForm = new MyForm();
myForm.Show();
...
```

The Form only will appear if ContinueLoadingForm() be true, this works with ShowDialog() and Application.Run() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on RCMAN's answer in this thread (which got me 99% of the way to the finish line)  ...

Here is the code I ended up using which also avoids the screen flicker:

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
Me.Opacity = 0.01
Me.MinimumSize = New Size(1, 1)
Me.Size = Me.MinimumSize
Me.Location = New Point(1, 1)
BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.Close))
```

Additionally, to avoid the message "This program might not have run correctly" I applied a manifest change as described by mik here:

[How to prevent "This program might not have installed correctly" messages on Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898220/how-to-prevent-this-program-might-not-have-installed-correctly-messages-on-vis)