# Can one edit an InstallShield setup.exe's manifest file?

Tags: windows, installshield, manifest, installshield-2009

I'm running into the Windows Vista/7 Program Compatibility Assistant problem described here:

["This program might not have installed correctly" message in Windows 7 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069135/this-program-might-not-have-installed-correctly-message-in-windows-7-rc)

The solution (backed-up by similar questions elsewhere, and MSDN), is apparently to add a 'compatibility' section to setup.exe's manifest.  InstallShield 10 SP1 does this automatically, but unfortunately I only have InstallShield 2009.

How would I go about editing the manifest?  Is there a way to do this programmatically, so I can integrate it into my build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the files named setupexe.*.manifest (Support or Program subfolder of InstallShield, I think) and edit or replace them. The appropriate one is selected and incorporated into setup.exe during build.

Comment: Looks like they're in (by default) C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2009\Support, and are called SetupExe.<type>.manifest, where <type> is one of Admin, Highest or Invoker.  Which one is used depends on what you selected in Release options.  http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q205850&sliceId=

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use [mt.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx) from the Windows SDK.

Comment: no, it doesn't work. the installer is truncated from ~107MB to ~110 KB after using mt.exe

Answer (score 1):

There is this [tool from InstallShield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22404877/281806) that can update the manifest. Or a direct link here: [isreman](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/HOWTO/Q113245). The provided example manifests do not supply the application compatibility section, though.

Answer (score 0):

a manifest file could be outside the exe, in the same path, or inside, in the resources of an exe.

Comment: InstallShield places a manifest in its bootstrap's resources. So since Vista (and possibly XP, I keep forgetting the cutoff) any external manifest will be ignored.