# SFX archive created with 7zip (7zS.sfx) triggers program compatibitity assistant

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, uac, 7zip, sfx

Today I created an SFX archive running a custom embedded program (not really an installer).
It works quite well in Windows 10.
When I run it from Windows 7 and close the embedded program window, I obtain the following error message : I get an error "This program might not have installed correctly".

How can I fix this ?

Note : I checked this thread, but could not test the sfx OS Major Version modification because PE Tools was detected as a virus : [How to do Vista/UAC aware self-extract installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229581/how-to-do-vista-uac-aware-self-extract-installer)