# Prevent Program Compatibility Wizard popping up after web deployment of Excel 2007 VSTO Addin

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, vsto, clickonce

Our Excel 2007 VSTO solution (built in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 using C# 3.5) is published via ClickOnce.

Clients deploy by clicking a URL using Internet Explorer that looks something like:

http://ourserver.com/ouraddin.vsto

It sometimes causes the Program Compatibility Wizard to pop up post-install and display  "This program might not have installed correctly ..."

Does anybody know any workarounds?

I found this post which talks about modifying the manifest files, but that seems to apply to regular ClickOnce solutions not VSTO.

[How to prevent "This program might not have installed correctly" messages on Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898220/how-to-prevent-this-program-might-not-have-installed-correctly-messages-on-vis)

I tried using the MageUI app to open the VSTO file and look for a way to embed the supportedOS tags but there was nowhere to put it.

I also found documentation on editing VSTO manifests, but would prefer not going down this route unless absolutely necessary as one would think the publish wizard out of the box should just work.

http://codeidol.com/csharp/c-sharp-in-office/Deployment/Editing-Manifests/

Perhaps there is a way to modify the source VSTO ClickOnce schemas in the build system to avoid editing the manifests as a post-build task?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Have you considered using an MSI to deploy your add-in? Windows supports it, as documented by Microsoft.

Comment: We initially chose the VSTO ClickOnce deployment to avoid having to do all the work of writing the correct regkeys based on which Office version users are running and having to write our own autoupdate mechanism (considering ClickOnce comes with one out of the box). I'd prefer having to go down that route unless absolutely necessary!