# Embed an installation program into a vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, embed, exe

I made a VB.NET project in which I check if the user has a folder on his own pc and if not, I launch a program to install within the missing folder all the needed files to run the application properly :

```
If Not Directory.Exists(dso_path) Then
            Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("DsoFileSetup_KB224351_x86.exe")
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            startInfo.Arguments = "/Q"
            Process.Start(startInfo)
        End If
```

The idea is to embed DsoFileSetup_KB224351_x86.exe in the application so that I could have a "stand-alone" final application. Right now, I need both "my_app.exe" and "DsoFileSetup_KB224351_x86.exe" to run my application. Is it possible to embed the second one into the first one ?

PS : I already tried this solution : [How do I make a self extract and running installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904532/how-do-i-make-a-self-extract-and-running-installer)
It's a good tutorial except that the final app always throws a message "This application may not be installed correctly". Actually, it's been installed correctly but the application I am working on must be for a commercial-use so, it has to be perfectly introduced to costumers.

Comment: Use [My.Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526.aspx).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898220/how-to-prevent-this-program-might-not-have-installed-correctly-messages-on-vis